# Why do we need to take the transpose of the data for PCA?

Tags: pca

I have the following dataset: we measured the temperature 1000 times in 9 different stations across the country. The data are represented in a matrix with 9 rows and 1000 columns. I wrote my own implementation of PCA and I have to reduce the dimensionality to 3. I did it and it works but I do not understand some things.

First of all some terminology. On wikipedia I read that the terms *variable* and *observation* are usually used. In my case, the observations would be the values of temperature and the variables the 9 stations?

Why do I have to take the transpose of the matrix, obtaining a $1000\times 9$ matrix, before doing the PCA?

Basically what I need to do is to try to *keep* the information of the original dataset by just using the temperature values of $3$ out of $9$ stations?

Comment: Clarification: in your own code, after you reduced the dimensionality to 3, what is the size of your data matrix? 3x1000? Also, what do you mean by "have to take the transpose"? Who says you *have to*? Do you have to do it in your own code? When using some standard functions (which ones)?

Comment: PCA often assumes that rows are observations, while columns are variables; that is the reason why you need to transpose.

You don't keep 3 of the original stations. 
What PCA does is to generate, through orthogonalization, new variables, which represent the original ones. In the first new variable, that we call 'component', you have a different loading for each one of the original stations.
The number of component to retain is not fixed and may vary depending on data. There are methods, like Parallel Analysis, which allows you to define how many components is better to retain.

Comment: @amoeba The matrix is 1000x3. Well, everything I read something about it, they transpose it... I do not *have to*.

Comment: Anyway, are you sure that PCA is a meaningful analysis in your case? What are your purposes?

Comment: It was just an assignment. I have already done it and it works. Just for clarification!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**We do not *need to*.**

It is a common and long-standing convention in statistics that data matrices have observations in rows and variables in columns. In your case, you indeed have $1000$ observations of $9$ variables. So it would be standard to organize your data in a matrix of $1000\times 9$ size. Most standard PCA implementations will expect to get such an input.

For example, `pca()` function in Matlab says this [on its help page](https://de.mathworks.com/help/stats/pca.html):

> `coeff = pca(X)` returns the principal component coefficients, also known as loadings, for the $n$-by-$p$ data matrix `X`. Rows of `X` correspond to observations and columns correspond to variables. The coefficient matrix is $p$-by-$p$.

But if you write your own code for PCA, you are free to follow an opposite convention and store variables in rows. I often did it myself this way.